# Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.example.srilanka.model.Employee'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm getting above mentioned error (`Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.example.srilanka.model.Employee'`) while engaging with spring boot project. I already referred all articles under this topic where in the stackoverflow as well as another tutorials. But I could not find a solution yet.

```
package com.example.srilanka.dao;
import com.example.srilanka.model.Employee;
import com.example.srilanka.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.List;

public class EmployeeDAO {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    /*to save an employee*/


    public Employee save(Employee emp){
        return employeeRepository.save(emp);
    }

    /*search all employees*/
    public List<Employee> findAll(){
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

    /*update an employee by id*/

    public Employee findOne(int empId){
        return employeeRepository.findOne(empId);  /*<----------error arise in here
    }

    /*get an employee*/

    /*delete an emmployee*/
}
```

my EmployeeRepository is in here

```
package com.example.srilanka.repository;

import com.example.srilanka.model.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

}
```

Comment: Please post the source code of your `EmployeeRepository` class. I belive it can help solve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation [findOne](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-jpa/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html#findOne-org.springframework.data.domain.Example-) return an  `Optional<S>`

```
public <S extends T> Optional<S> findOne(Example<S> example)
```

So instead you have two ways `.orElse(null)`, to get even the object or null if it is not present :

```
return employeeRepository.findOne(empId).orElse(null);
```

else change the type of your method to `Optional`

```
public Optional<Employee> findOne(int empId) {
    return employeeRepository.findOne(empId);
}
```

or you can even use `orElseThrow` to throw an exception if the object not exist.

Comment: It's dangerous to use employeeRepository.findOne(empId).get() without calling isPresent() first because it may raise NullPointerException if entity is not found

Comment: @amseager you are correct, you can use `orElse(null)` or `orElseThrow` in this case

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you've updated `Spring-data-jpa` dependency.

The previous signature of this method in `CrudRepository` was:

```
T findOne(ID id);
```

Now (since 2.0 version) it became (in `QueryByExampleExecutor`):

```
<S extends T> Optional<S> findOne(Example<S> example);
```

But don't worry - you can use `Optional<T> findById(ID id);` from `CrudRepository`